# Shopify import fails with no error

Tags: import, runtime-error, shopify

Today, I watched as a friend tried to import her product inventory spreadsheet, using the Shopify spreadsheet template and the default import function, it seemed like the import was working; that is, it ran for a reasonable amount of time. It did not show an error, but the products were not imported. Is this common with Shopify?

Based on comments in various online discussions, there seems to be some error trapping in the import function, but we certainly didn't see it.

Comment: Are you referring to the product import with the CSV file or a specific app for import?

Comment: My friend created a CSV file, per template supplied by Shopify. Then she used the Import function (button) in the Products section of the site. At this point, there are no apps added to her account.

Comment: Create a sample product with the same values and export it. You will get a proper CSV file that you can compare it against your one, since this seems like a bad CSV file.

Comment: Try importing with this app - it will show the result for each row, if there will be any errors: https://excelify.io

Comment: What a super idea! I will send it to my friend and report how it works!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this one instance, the problem was that the image addresses were not ones that Shopify could use. Once the images were imported into the system, one-by-one, the errors disappeared. From this correction, I would answer the original question to be that an import into Shopify could often fail without indication and without error messages.